# Using cURL with 127.0.0.1 to connect to django dev server is not working

Tags: python, django

If I start my django dev server using the command `python manage.py runserver` I can connect to it using the command (from another terminal) `curl http://localhost:8000/` but I can't connect with `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, the terminal responds "503 Service Unavailable".

**Question:** Are 127.0.0.1 and localhost not supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is translated to 127.0.0.1 but if you got a 503 error, it means you have another HTTP server **replying** on port 8000.

You could have another instance running. (Apache, other Django instance, etc) Check twice.

Verify with netstat if needed.

And then try to run:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

To bind the dev server on every addresses.

If it doesn't work, try to launch the devserver again on a different port.

Comment: If some other web server is active besides Django, why using localhost does work? I've tried running runserver as you describe, but the result is the same

Comment: Can you try to run the server on a different port? `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888`

Comment: The same thing happens. It connects using `curl http://localhost:8888/` but not with `curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/`